# How to reduce the width of <mat-sidenav-content>?

Tags: angular

I am using a sidenavigation which is being rendered on a page initially along with a mat-sidenav-content.The issue is that I have configured a router and when i click on one of the menus in the side nav,the component is also being rendered but it is going below in the page.I meant that the component is being rendered towards the bottom of the page instead of coming up as a whole on the screen.How can i fix it?

Comment: Issue is in your routing structure, you need to have one parent component with sidenav bar and sidenav bar content will behaving the router-outlet to render component in that

Comment: @vishal can you  pls elaborate,I didnt get you

Comment: Create a http://stackblitz.com , then we can easily look into the issue

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in your parent component html file, and then you can define the routing structure with all the routes as child routes of this component, which needs to be rendered

```
<mat-sidenav-container>
   <mat-sidenav>
       // Here you will be showing the menu items
   <mat-sidenav>
   <mat-sidenav-content>
       <router-outlet></router-outlet>
   </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```